# Finding values from a table that are *not* in a grouping of another table and what group that value is missing from?

Tags: sql-server-2008, missing-data

I hope I am not missing something very simple here.  I have done a Google search(es) and searched through Stack Overflow.

Here is the situation:  For simplicity's sake let's say I have a table called "PeoplesDocs", in a SQL Server 2008 DB, that holds a bunch of people and all the documents that they own.  So one person can have several documents.  I also have a table called "RequiredDocs" that simply holds all the documents that a person should have.  Here is sort of what it looks like:

PeoplesDocs:

```
PersonID   DocID  
--------   -----  
1          A  
1          B  
1          C  
1          D  
2          C  
2          D  
3          A  
3          B  
3          C
```

RequiredDocs:

```
DocID     DocName  
-----     ---------  
A         DocumentA  
B         DocumentB  
C         DocumentC  
D         DocumentD
```

How do I write a SQL query that returns some variation of:

```
PersonID   MissingDocs  
--------   -----------  
2          DocumentA  
2          DocumentB  
3          DocumentD
```

I have tried, and most of my searching has pointed to, something like:

```
SELECT DocID  
FROM DocsRequired  
WHERE NOT EXIST IN (  
SELECT DocID FROM PeoplesDocs)
```

but obviously this will not return anything in this example because everyone has at least one of the documents.

Also, if a person does not have any documents then there will be one record in the PeoplesDocs table with the DocID set to NULL.

Comment: Do you have a table of "Peoples" ?

Comment: Yes.  The PeoplesDocs table in reality is group of tables.  I simplified the problem so I could ask about just the the crux of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
Select ...
From RequiredDocs As RD
    Cross Join People As P
Where Not Exists(
                Select 1
                From PeoplesDocs As PD1
                Where PD1.PersonId = P.PersonId
                    And PD1.DocId = RD.DocId
                )
```

Comment: Wow... pretty close to what I just wrote :P ... too bad you beat me to it, but mine looks prettier :)

Comment: @Timothy Khouri: NOT EXISTS is safer and different to NOT IN: with NULLs they will will give very different results

Comment: @Thomas: Why "EXISTS(SELECT 1"? You could use "EXISTS (SELECT 1/0" because it's **never** evaluated. Try it ;-)

Comment: @gbn - Habit. I used to use Select * in Exists functions but have come to use a constant so I can easily search for and eliminate any uses of Select * in code. I have to put something there so I just put a 1.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help.  I should of been able to figure out that!  darn it! ;-)  I am implementing Thomas' solution right now.  The example I provided was *very* simplified, in actuality I have 100s of 1000s of records and that is just a subset of the entire data set, so weeding though it all to validate is .... daunting, to say the least! :-P

Thanks again!!

Ben

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    p.PersonID,
    rd.DocName AS MissingDocs
FROM
    dbo.People p, dbo.RequiredDocs rd
WHERE
    rd.DocID NOT IN (SELECT pd.DocID FROM dbo.PeoplesDocs pd
        WHERE pd.PersonID = p.PersonID)
```